# ViewPager with List of Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Hello to everyone i have a problem with a `ViewPager`; this is my code...

```
public class FragmentViewPager extends Fragment {

ArrayList<Prodotto> listaProdotti = new ArrayList<Prodotto>();

public int posizione;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_pager, container, false);
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) root.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    MyPagerAdapter mPageAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), this.posizione);
    pager.setAdapter(mPageAdapter);
    pager.setCurrentItem(this.posizione);


    return root;
}


private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public int posizioneIniziale;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int posizione) {

        super(fm);
        this.posizioneIniziale = posizione;

        //this.getItem(posizione);

    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {

        //pos = this.posizioneIniziale;
        Log.w(null, "Posizione del fragment selezionato: " + pos);
        FragmentVisualizzaProdotto fragment = new FragmentVisualizzaProdotto();
        fragment.urlImmagine = listaProdotti.get(pos).getUrlImmagine();
        fragment.nomeProdotto = listaProdotti.get(pos).getDescrizione();
        fragment.prezzo = listaProdotti.get(pos).getPrezzo();
        Log.w(null, "Nome e Prezzo del fragment selezionato: " + fragment.nomeProdotto + " e " + fragment.prezzo);
        fragment.commento = listaProdotti.get(pos).getCommento();
        //this.posizione = pos;
        return fragment;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listaProdotti.size();
    }


 }
    }
```

The problem is that when i scroll the element of the `ViewPager` it take element from other list of the `ArrayList` (different from those passed in MyPagerAdapter) can anyone help me? thanks in advance

Comment: You are not passing any array list in your adapter class

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the code passing arrayList in adapter, so...

```
public class FragmentViewPager extends Fragment {

ArrayList<Prodotto> listaProdotti = new ArrayList<Prodotto>();

public int posizione;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_pager, container, false);
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) root.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    MyPagerAdapter mPageAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), this.posizione, listaProdotti);
    pager.setAdapter(mPageAdapter);
    pager.setCurrentItem(this.posizione);


    return root;
}


private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public int posizioneIniziale;
    ArrayList<Prodotto> listaProdotti = new ArrayList<Prodotto>();

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int posizione, ArrayList<Prodotto> listaProdotti) {

        super(fm);
        this.posizioneIniziale = posizione;
        this.listaProdotti = listaProdotti;

        //this.getItem(posizione);

    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {

        //pos = this.posizioneIniziale;
        Log.w(null, "Posizione del fragment selezionato: " + pos);
        FragmentVisualizzaProdotto fragment = new FragmentVisualizzaProdotto();
        fragment.urlImmagine = listaProdotti.get(pos).getUrlImmagine();
        fragment.nomeProdotto = listaProdotti.get(pos).getDescrizione();
        fragment.prezzo = listaProdotti.get(pos).getPrezzo();
        Log.w(null, "Nome e Prezzo del fragment selezionato: " + fragment.nomeProdotto + " e " + fragment.prezzo);
        fragment.commento = listaProdotti.get(pos).getCommento();
        //this.posizione = pos;
        return fragment;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listaProdotti.size();
    }



}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This will not help you but some advices:
1. Do not use getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), but use getChildFragmentManger()
2. Do not set values like you do

```
FragmentVisualizzaProdotto fragment = new FragmentVisualizzaProdotto();
        fragment.urlImmagine = listaProdotti.get(pos).getUrlImmagine();
        fragment.nomeProdotto = listaProdotti.get(pos).getDescrizione();
        fragment.prezzo = listaProdotti.get(pos).getPrezzo();
        Log.w(null, "Nome e Prezzo del fragment selezionato: " + fragment.nomeProdotto + " e " + fragment.prezzo);
        fragment.commento = listaProdotti.get(pos).getCommento();
```

Use arguments.

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
arg.put()//put params
fragment.setArguments(args)
```